# Asp.Net MVC 5 mixing Windows authentication with a role provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to mix Windows authentication, with my own Role Provider - but I can't seem to get it to recognise "IsUserInRole("....","...")"

I added a new class to my Models -> Security folder, named MTRoleProvider:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace wb.Models.Security 
{
public class MTRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private BoardContext db = new BoardContext();

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        var roleNames = db.UserRole.Where(x => x.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(x => x.Role);

        if (roleNames.Count() > 0)
            return roleNames.ToArray();
        else
            return new string[] { }; 
    }


    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        var user = db.UserRole.Where(x => x.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.Role.Equals(roleName,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (user != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
    }

}
}
```

In my web.config - I added this to system.web:

```
<roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="MTRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MTRoleProvider" type="wb.Models.Security.MTRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I also added:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Then in my _layout.cshtml file, I tried to use it like this:

```
 @if(IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name,"Admin"))
   {
      <text>Admin mode</text>
   }
```

User.Identity.Name should give my Windows username (which it does), but `IsUserInRole` is underlined in Red.

[image]

How can I get the system to recognise my new provider?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: Isn't it `Roles.IsUserInRole`?

Comment: Where is the method "IsUserInRole" used in your View defined?  With a RoleProvider I'd expect you to simply use "if(User.IsInRole("Admin")".  If your RoleProvider is configured correctly (which it appears to be), `User` should be an instance of `RolePrincipal` which contains the roles supplied by your custom RoleProvider.

Comment: Hi - it's defined in the MTRoleProvider.cs file - in the Models -> Security folder - thanks

Comment: check this http://bojanskr.blogspot.in/2011/12/custom-role-provider.html

Comment: Hi Malkam - that looks exactly like my code - but even with a breakpoint in the code at IsUserInRole - it's not getting hit. Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Extesion Method:

```
 public static bool IsUserInRole(this HtmlHelper helper, string username, string roleName)
    {
       // your code
    }
```

then in your view:

```
@if(Html.IsUserInRole(userName, Role))
```

Comment: Hi Mike - thank you - where would I add the code for the extension method?

Comment: in your MTRoleProvider class. make sure it's static too.
also add @using wb.Models.Security.MTRoleProvider in your view

Comment: Hi - if I do that, it then doesn't recognise by db context defined at the top of the MTRoleProvider class/code - the "db" part is underlined in red.

Comment: private static BoardContext db = new BoardContext();